# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

this is the error i get when trying to use the datepicker widget: *has no method

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#from").datepicker({
            ....         
            }
        });
        $("#to").datepicker({
           ....
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the include file i'm using.
The confusing part of this is that I use this same includes file on 3 pages and I only get the error on the one page. so it cant really be the script itself...I think

```
<!-- Datepicker widget -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

any Ideas?

Comment: Include the datepicker file *above* this code.

Comment: I have this is what it looks like
<!-- Datepicker widget -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Which one is the datepicker file?

Comment: You included custom.js twice. (min.js is the same as .js)

Comment: Is it that page in the same directory as other working pages?

Comment: check your browswer's network tag to see whether all the js files are downloaded

Comment: also test `$ == jQuery` to see whether any other library is overriding jQuery library

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed there was a jQuery conflict on $
added a `jQuery(function($){` which did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, it was caused by incorrectly using a mix of primefaces and richfaces - specifically when using `p:calendar` inside `a4j:outputPanel`.

Using `p:outputPanel` instead and removing the `a4j` namespace resolved the issue.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour to get to know how this site works and what it is for. Consider formatting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the above solution worked for me too!  Here is the complete code for anyone not completely sure...   jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});